# Explicit tensor product of isocrystals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L$ be the completion of the maximal unramified extension of $\mathbb Q_p$. Let $\sigma$ be a topological generator for the Galois group of $L/\mathbb Q_p$. Say that $(D, \phi)$ is an isocrystal over $L$ if $D$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $L$ and $\phi$ is a $\sigma$-linear automorphism of $D$.
Let $L\langle\phi\rangle$ be the twisted polynomial ring over $L$ such that $\phi c = \sigma(c) \phi$, for $c \in L$. Then we can define explicit isocrystals by setting $$D(r/s) = L \langle \phi \rangle / (\phi^r - p^s),$$ where $r/s \in \mathbb Q$ and $gcd(r, s) = 1$. As an $L$-vector space this is of dimension $r$. It is well known that every isocrystal over $L$ is a direct sum of isocrystals of this form. Furthermore, there is a tensor product given by
$$D(r/s) \otimes D(r'/s') = (D(r/s + r'/s'))^{\oplus gcd(r, r')},$$
see for example equation 15 [here](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/%7Edeshalit/new_site/files/F-isocrystals.pdf).

I've been struggling to make explicit the isomorphism giving rise to this tensor product. Let us assume for simplicity that $gcd(r, r') = 1$. Then we need to find an isomorphism
$$L\langle \phi \rangle /(\phi^r - p^s) \otimes_L L\langle \phi \rangle /(\phi^{r'} - p^{s'}) \to L\langle \phi \rangle /(\phi^{rs'+r's} - p^{ss'}).$$
How is this map defined?

Comment: What is a $\sigma$-linear automorphism?

Comment: @reuns an automorphism $\phi$ of $D$ satisfying $\phi(cd) = \sigma(c) \phi(d)$, for $c \in L$ and $d \in D$.

Comment: Does the twisted non-commutative ring structure change anything? The isomorphism is obvious when replacing $L\langle \phi \rangle /(\phi^r - p^s)$ by $L[x]/(x^r-p^s)$.

Comment: @reuns Are you thinking of $\phi \otimes_L \phi \leftarrow \phi$? It's not obvious to me that this gives the correct $L$-dimensions...

Comment: It does give the right dimensions because the left $L$-module structure is the same as for $L[x]/(x^r-p^s)\cong L(p^{s/r})$

Comment: @reuns could you please explain how this can lead to the the tensor product of $D(r/s)$ and $D(r'/s')$ having dimension different from $rr'$?

Comment: I think you inverted $r$ and $s$, ie. $D(s/r)$ instead of $D(r/s)$, and that the dimension is $rr'$.